# how to run terminal command on startup

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal, linux-mint

I want to run below commands on startup of linux mint os. which will enable my laptop touchpad two finger scroll.

```
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1

xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1 1

xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 32 10

xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width" 32 8
```

Comment: Which shell are you using? Couldn't it just go into your [.bashrc](http://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file) or [.profile](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45684/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile)?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on you WindowManager you could use its autorun feature to run the script.

I know the following does not answer the question, but why don't you configure the synaptics driver in you xorg configuration?

http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.xhtml

- xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1
  Not sure what this is.
- xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1 1
  Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "boolean"
  Enable vertical scrolling when dragging with two fingers anywhere on the touchpad. Property: "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling"
  Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "boolean"
  Enable horizontal scrolling when dragging with two fingers anywhere on the touchpad. Property: "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling"
- xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 32 10
  Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "integer"
  For touchpads not capable of detecting multiple fingers (Alps), this sets the Z pressure threshold to emulate a two finger press. Property: "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure"
  O
- xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width" 32 8
  Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinW" "integer"
  Some touchpads report a two-finger touch as wide finger. This sets the finger width threshold to emulate a two finger press. This feature works best with (PalmDetect) off. Property: "Synaptics Two-Finger Width"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which shell you are using (which you've not responded to yet), you could just put these start up commands in a startup script. This is where you would typically personalise your linux/ unix env. See the links below to get the idea...

- [.bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file) file if you use the bash shell
- [.profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45684/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile) for bourne shells (e.g. ksh, zsh [and bash again])